# When should I vote to delete answers that I wouldn't flag?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I recently asked [When should I vote to delete answers that I wouldn't flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269877/when-should-i-vote-to-delete-answers-that-i-wouldnt-flag) on the mother meta, but so far haven't gotten a lot of feedback. Since ELL is the only site I can currently directly delete answers on, I figured I might as well go ahead and ask here: what's the long tail of answers that I should be *voting to delete* that I wouldn't necessarily *flag* or vote in review to *recommend deletion*? Anyone have some specific examples?

Comment: Interesting question. Too bad it's been neglected here and there. I really wonder what the answer is.

Comment: I can't think of any circumstance where you wouldn't be willing to *recommend* deletion, but would be willing to actually *vote* to delete (or vice-versa). Besides, unless you're a mod or you have [close-vote superpowers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254589/), your "vote" to delete is effectively just a "recommendation" anyway, since it won't be actioned unless 4 other users also vote the same way.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: *2 others. Also, post owners can't undelete if I voted to delete, whereas a review outcome of Delete can be reversed unilaterally.

Comment: I don't get that. Are you saying a) a question is deleted if *three* (not five) users vote to delete it, and b) an OP can unilaterally undelete his own post if it got deleted via the review queue? Both of those points are news to me, but I admit I don't study such things assiduously. The only difference I'm aware of is that if you don't perform actions *within* the review queue, you won't earn review badges.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Yes to both. Deleting posts usually only requires three delete voters. Deleting *answers* never takes more, and deleting *questions* only takes more if they have a high score. (And, of course, delete votes don't require someone else to flag the post first.)

Comment: oic. I've never understood what actually causes the "delete" option to become available on Qs or As (I just figured it was something to do with "number of downvotes").

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Answers have to be negatively scored; questions just have to be closed. (And for 2k plebes :P, questions have to be closed for 48 hours first.)

Comment: But if it's from the review queue, you can vote to delete a zero-scored answer, I believe.

Comment: Let's delete them all and start from scratch is what I say.